# Python - use of 'self' - noob here going crazy trying to understand it

Tags: python, class

I have a simple socket class: **MySocketLib.py** ..

```
import socket

class socklib():
    def create_tcp_serversocket(self,port):
        serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), port))
        serversocket.listen(5) 
        return serversocket

    def send_msg(self, sock, msg, msglen):
         ... blah blah ...  

    def recv_msg(self, sock, msglen):
         ... blah blah ....
```

My main file is **Server.py** as follows:

```
import MySocketLib

class serverclass(): 

    def __init__(self,port):
        self.servsock = 0
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.servsock = self.create_tcp_serversocket(self.port)
        (clientsock, address) = self.servsock.accept() # ERROR: 'SELF' not defined
        ... blah blah ... 

#############################
###   Main startup code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = serverclass(2000) # server is on port 2000
    server.run()
```

I keep getting the below error:

```
File "D:\CodeLearn\Server.py", line 14, in serverclass
(clientsock, address) = self.servsock.accept()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I can't seem to get a handle on the concept of "self". Some times, it seems to be needed and sometimes not.  Why would i need to define 'self' here when it is a python keyword?

---

Thanks everyone ... it was indeed the tabs and spacing issues.  I use eclipse and in preferences I have set "Editor" preferences to use spaces when tabbing.

Comment: How are `serverclass` and `socklib` related?

Comment: Also, in the code you're showing relevant error is not on line 14, but on line 11. I guess you're not actually showing us what is giving you this error, are you?

Comment: where did you read that `self` is a Python keyword?

Comment: I am guessing that you have a mixture of tabs and spaces in your code. If the above the error is indented with spaces and the line of the error has a tab you would get this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use tabs in Python source code. Configure your editor to always use spaces.

`self` is not a Python keyword, it's a convention. It's the usual name for the "instance" of a class you're using. Example:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, v): self.v = v

a = X(1)
b = X(2)
print a.v, b.v
```

When this code runs, the Python runtime will eventually allocate memory for two instances of `X` which it will assign to `a` and `b` respectively. If there wasn't something like `self`, you would have to write:

```
a = X()
a.v = 1
b = X()
b.b = 2
print a.v, b.v
```

And you would get an error because you wrote `b.b` instead of `b.v`. Moreover, calling methods would be outright ugly:

```
class X:
    def set(v): ???.v = v
```

How would you say "access the reference `v` which was allocated in `__init__` of `X`"?

One solution would be to pass the instance reference (the pointer to the memory which was allocated for `X`) as a parameter:

```
class X:
    def set(a, v): a.v = v

a.set(a, 1) # Holy ugly!
```

Everyone would use different names and we would all violate DRY and it would be a mess. So what Python did is:

```
class X:
    def set(self, v): self.v = v

a.set(1) # while "set" runs, "self" == "a"
b.set(2) # while "set" runs, "self" == "b"
```

That said, I have no idea why the code above fails. `self` is obviously defined or the error would already happen in the first line of your `run()` method. So my guess is that you mixed spaces and tabs for indentation and that confuses Python and it sees:

```
def run(self):
    self.servsock = self.create_tcp_serversocket(self.port)
(clientsock, address) = self.servsock.accept() # ERROR: 'SELF' not defined
```

Then it would try to evaluate `self.servsock.accept()` while it parses the class definition. At that time, there is no instance yet (the class doesn't exist!) so `self` is not available either.

Conclusion: Never mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe indentation error. 
File

```
"D:\CodeLearn\Server.py", line 14, in serverclass
```

This meen that

```
(clientsock, address) = self.servsock.accept()
```

is not inside **run** function, but in **serverclass** itself

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong, so `__init__()` and `run()` are being interpreted as top-level functions -- with no automatic `self` parameter. What you need is:

```
class serverclass:

    def __init__(self,port):
        self.servsock = 0
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.servsock = self.create_tcp_serversocket(self.port)
        (clientsock, address) = self.servsock.accept() # ERROR: 'SELF' not defined
        ... blah blah ...
```

Comment: If it will be so then AttributeError will occur at line with server.run()

Comment: Will be "AttributeError: serverclass instance has no attribute 'run'"